# Anonymising a postgres database stored in Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

The preferred method for anonymising postgres dumps seems to be using [Postgresql Anonymizer](https://postgresql-anonymizer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/INSTALL/).

This is unsupported by RDS, meaning you have to upload an SQL file manually which adds the extension. I've done that following the steps [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/306661/how-to-install-postgresql-anonymizer-0-8-1-on-amazon-rds) However as the installation was not done on the postgres machine itself, there are various data folders missing. The SQL file includes the lines

```
  SELECT bool_or(results) INTO success
  FROM unnest(array[
    anon.load_csv('anon.identifiers_category',datapath||'/identifiers_category.csv'),
    anon.load_csv('anon.identifier',datapath ||'/identifier_fr_FR.csv'),
    anon.load_csv('anon.identifier',datapath ||'/identifier_en_US.csv'),
    anon.load_csv('anon.city',datapath ||'/city.csv'),
    anon.load_csv('anon.company',datapath ||'/company.csv'),
    anon.load_csv('anon.email', datapath ||'/email.csv'),
    anon.load_csv('anon.first_name',datapath ||'/first_name.csv'),
    anon.load_csv('anon.iban',datapath ||'/iban.csv'),
    anon.load_csv('anon.last_name',datapath ||'/last_name.csv'),
    anon.load_csv('anon.siret',datapath ||'/siret.csv'),
    anon.load_csv('anon.lorem_ipsum',datapath ||'/lorem_ipsum.csv')
  ]) results;
  RETURN success;
```

Which all obviously fail as there are no CSV's present.

I guess my first question is, are there any other options for anonymising a postgres database hosted in RDS outside of Postgresql Anonymizer?

And if the route I'm taking is the right one, how can I upload fake data? Is there any way for me to simply include it raw in the SQL file itself? Or access the file structure of the postgres machine that's hosting our database and insert the CSV files that way?

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out a solution to this?

Comment: I didn't, I'll add what i did as a workaround as a solution but it's not great

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't answer my problem it may help others in my situation.

I gave up trying to anonymise directly in RDS, and instead downloaded the production dump locally. I then added these lines to the bottom:

```
UPDATE public.user SET phone_number = '+444444444-' || public.user.id;
UPDATE public.guest SET phone_number = '+444444444-' || public.guest.id;
```

I then import this dump locally, and dump this into a fresh SQL file which gets uploaded to S3 and is fully anonymised.

Once you setup I script to do this it's just one or two commands whenever you need a fresh data dump, but again if there was a solution within RDS that would be preferrable

Comment: And how did you anonymised on s3? using macie?

Comment: I put the lines from my answer at the bottom of the SQL file. You can just manually update every column you need to to a default value